# About Integer values

Tags: java, android, math, integer

I need to make a variable which store the version of a database, the value will be modified by me everytime I modify the db.

I've been thinking of use the date in format YYYYMMDD, i.e. 20150319. But I don't know if the next values, as 20150320, 20150321... will be bigger.

```
int database_version = 20150319;
```

Some mathematics in the room?

Thanks for all.

Comment: You want to use the `final int DATABASE_VERSION = xyz;` constant of your database helper class. And **yes**, `20150320 is bigger than 20150319`.

Comment: yyyymmdd – you can use as timestamp, ie long

Comment: I don't understand you. :-/

Comment: You can use something like this:
   'String date = "20150319";'
   'int i = Integer.parseInt(date);'

Comment: My question is if the values of next days will be bigger everytime I sum a day. I don't know If I explain me.

Comment: **Yes**, they will! 20150320 = 20150319 + 1. Very basic algebra...

Comment: I don't want to find a case in which an integer date will be bigger than the previous stored date. Thanks.

Comment: If you want the `onUpgrade()` method to fire, the next value of **DATABASE_VERSION** has to be **bigger**.

Comment: out of all questions, why can't you just start from 1 and 1 to the last version every time you update the database?

Comment: Thanks Der Golem, it's usefull everytime to know algebra at basic levels :). It's not my case xD

Comment: use i==0 or 1 . when you update the database, increment the value of i. also you have to store it to sharedpreferences.

Comment: I think he wants to remember WHEN the database was changed. Which will ALWAYS be a future date (bigger int), in respect to the old one.

Comment: Yes, the idea is to know when I change the DB. I was using a simple int, but it is not very descriptive. So I think to use the date in format YYYYMMDD and store as a simple int, but I was not sure that an old value were lower than a new one.

Comment: Unless you can travel in time (if you can, please teach me how to), your dates will be always **future** (that means **bigger**), in respect to the previous ones.

Answer (score 2):

If the date is written in the correct order (YYYYMMDD), the new dates will always be bigger than the older ones. As time does increase continuously the integer will also increase continuously.